# How to use schema.org extensions in html?

Tags: schema.org

I'm new to schema.org, and I understand the basics and how to use the standard schema.org types. But how do you use this extension in html in a web site?

For a schema.org type like SoftwareApplication, you would refer to it as https://schema.org/SoftwareApplication:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/SoftwareApplication">
```

So is it correct if I refer to software_type's SoftwareLibrary (https://w3id.org/software-types) like this: https://w3id.org/software-types/SoftwareLibrary?

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="https://w3id.org/software-types/SoftwareLibrary">
```

Googling around I also see https://w3id.org/software-types#SoftwareLibrary being used, so using the # character instead of the / character.

I've googled for a few hours for a tutorial on schema extensions, but I get lost in the w3c forest of murky documentation.

EDIT 1 (8/20/2023): Would this be a correct way to do it with html + microdata?

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="https://w3id.org/software-types/SoftwareLibrary">
    <div itempprop="name">Name of my software library</div>
    <div itempprop="executableName">mysoftwarelibrary.dll</div>
</div>
```

As I understand it, SoftwareLibrary is defined as a sub type of SoftwareApplication, and I don't have to actually reference SoftwareApplication explicitly? Like when you would set itemtype to SoftwareApplication, you also wouldn't need to reference its parent type CreativeWork.

Comment: ```<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/SoftwareApplication">``` is used to identify the schema used. All the customizable fields are provided in the Schema link you shared. Check out the examples on the page for a better understanding.

Comment: I'm super confused by the relations between things. I guess the key phrase is "All proposed classes extend schema:SoftwareApplication". But then in the json-ld examples, they specify "@type": "SoftwareSourceCode". And the statement below: "The link between SoftwareSourceCode and subclasses of SoftwareApplication, WebAPI, WebPage or WebSite is established using the targetProduct property.".

So how does this translate to the html syntax, is there somewhere documentation that teaches me how to do this?

Comment: I've added an edit to my question with how I understand it works with html/microdata.

Comment: ```https://w3id.org/software-types/SoftwareLibrary``` is not a valid declaration. Declaring itemtype has to be one defined in Schema.org. In your case, it'll be ```https://schema.org/SoftwareApplication```. Schema.org is a global structure to define what an element on a web page is. You can see all the defined schema types here ```https://schema.org/docs/full.html```. The ```itemtype``` property is used to indicate what type of schema that particular element on the webpage is.

Comment: If you have a ```<code>...</code>``` element on your page and want to add a schema to it, you'll add the ```itemtype``` as ```https://schema.org/SoftwareSourceCode```

Comment: Hmm, from the documentation on schema.org I understood the tree could be extended by outside parties. So there can be extension, but not for itemtype?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254981/discussion-between-hymnzzy-and-wout).

Comment: OK, let me try that, I've never used the stackoverflow chat before.